# How i can reduce size or stream of image in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to reduce size of image which i am selecting from gallery using Plugin.Media .Here is my code

```
 var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
        });


        if (file == null)
            return;


        AppApplication.Instance().NewImage = file.GetStream();

        ProfileIcon.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });
```

How i can reduce size or stream of image in xamarin forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set PhotoSize to Small to reduce the size to 25% of the original. You currently have it set to Medium which is 50%

You can also set CustomPhotoSize to a percentage.

Another setting is Compression which reduces the storage size but affects the quality of the image. Try setting this to 90.

[All the things I said and more can be found on the MediaPlugin github page](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#photo--video-settings)